# Determine if a word is a reserved word in Apache Derby

Tags: java, jdbc, derby, reserved-words

Is there a way to escape only the columns that are reserved words?

For example, I'd like to generate the following statement using java:

```
create table person(id int, name varchar(255), "year" int);
```

Notice that "year" has to be escaped because it's a reserved word? Is there a way to determine if a string is a reserved word?

The reason I don't just escape all the columns is because I'd rather have queries look like this:

```
select id, name, "year" from person
```

Rather than this:

```
select "id", "name", "year" from person
```

Comment: How about not using reserved words? In example case, what is `year` representing? Year of birth? If so, why not call it that? Makes it easier for others too, to know what it is.

Comment: It's SQL. https://db.apache.org/derby/docs/10.2/ref/rrefkeywords29722.html

Comment: Thanks Andreas, "year" was just an example. I'm generating tables programmatically. The columns actually represent fields in dozens of different classes.

Comment: Thanks Dave. Does java provide a method that returns "true" when a String is a reserved word?

Comment: If you're generating the tables and their queries programmatically, just put quotes around **all** the table and column names. There's no reason not to, and that way you're safe even if the SQL standards committee adds new reserved words in the future.

Comment: Thanks Bryan. Yes that's what I'm doing at the moment. It just means that whenever I write a query to get data out of the database I have to use quotes everywhere. I was hoping the java database interface would force database vendors to provide a reserved keyword list and then expose it somehow.

Comment: *"I was hoping the java database interface would force database vendors ..."*. JDBC is not well known for *forcing* database vendors to do anything.

Comment: There is, [`DatabaseMetaData.getSQLKeywords()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/DatabaseMetaData.html#getSQLKeywords--) but it only contains the words reserved on top of the  SQL:2003 keywords (and only if the driver vendor bothers with keeping it up to date and complete), so you would still need to have your own list of SQL:2003 keywords. There are plans for JDBC 4.3 to contain metadata functions to quote object names if necessary.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From a generic JDBC perspective, there is a way of determining the keywords, using the SQL:2003 keywords list (which you need to obtain yourself) + the result of [`DatabaseMetaData.getSQLKeywords()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/DatabaseMetaData.html#getSQLKeywords--):

> Retrieves a comma-separated list of all of this database's SQL keywords that are NOT also SQL:2003 keywords.

However this depends on the list of keywords in the JDBC driver being complete and up to date, which is not always the case. I don't know if that is the case for Derby or not. If you are writing generic software it is better to always quote to avoid the hassle.

There are plans to include functionality in JDBC 4.3 to quote object names (that is given a string it will either return the string as is (no quoting necessary), quoted if necessary or throws an `SQLException` if the object name is invalid or quoting is not possible). This isn't final IIRC, and would then need to wait for driver vendors to implements it..